# how to play video in iphone for which url is coming from service

Tags: iphone, html5-video

I want to play video in my `iPhone`.

```
NSString *myHTML =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\<html>\<head>\<body>\%@</body>\</html>", summary];//here summary is my url
[webView2 loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```

if I give the url statically its working fine iam able to play the video,but my url is coming from server like this

```
      <iframe width="560" height="314' src="http://www.youtube.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   // iam getting this from service.
```

if I proceed in the same way to load video its not working it's just showing total string in my view.
   how to rectify this issue shall I need to get only source from that string(url)or is there any other way?

here i may get youtube video or mp4 or mov but not flash.(ios doesn't suppor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Service Response is in XML Format. First of all you need to do is to perform XML Parsing. For XML Parsing there are several Tutorials available. Some of the Links are :

1. [Super easy iOS XML parsing](http://vuknikolic.me/2012/04/27/super-easy-ios-xml-parsing/)
2. [Parsing XML with Objective-C](http://www.cbeninati.com/i/?p=131)
3. [How to Parse XML Files in Xcode](http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad-App-Dev/a/How-To-Parse-Xml-Files-In-Xcode-Objective-C.htm)

After parsing, Extract the data you want and Store it in some Variables or Arrays. Then use that data to play the Video. You can check these Links :

1. [YouTube API Blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)
2. [Playing Video on the iPhone and iPad](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44642)

Be Relax. It's so simple. Just follow the above steps and you will get the Result you want.

**Update :**

If your string look like `myString` mentioned in the below example then you can use the below code to get the URL.

```
NSString *myString = @"&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;314&#39;&#39; src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
NSRange firstRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"http://"];
NSRange secondRange = [[myString substringFromIndex:firstRange.location] rangeOfString:@"&quot;"];
NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange(firstRange.location, secondRange.location);
NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange:finalRange];
NSLog(@"subString :: %@",subString);
```

GoodLuck !!!

Comment: actually my ifrmae is coming fron service

Comment: @siva : I am talking about the Response Format. Is it in XML Form ?

Comment: i converted it  into noraml string by using   https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

Comment: is there any way to get src value from iframe

Comment: @siva: Take a look at my **Update** Section and your problem should be solved.

Comment: one more issue, actually my client may upload content or video or both. how to know my client has uploaded video in his page

Comment: @siva : As I told you in your last Question, you should ask another Question for different issues.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you want to play video in `MPMoviePlayerController` then use bellow code...

you can play video in `MPMoviePlayerController` like bellow...

```
MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
[videoPlayer play];
```

see whole example from this link [Code for Play Video in iPhone](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44642)

Also see another Demo for play the video in iPhone from this link

[AVPlayer](http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66)

**UPDATE :**

**2.** If you want to play video in `webView` then use bellow code...

```
NSString *Str = @"<video controls> <source src=\"yourvideofile.mp4\"> </video>";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourvideofile" ofType:@"mp4"];
[Webview loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

i hope its useful to you...

Comment: as per question video need to play in `webView` not in `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: here user is new and i suggest that use `MPMoviePlayerController` instead of use `webView` , it is very easy so..

Comment: see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401531/how-to-play-a-video-from-an-url-in-iphone from here you can see how to play video also if you want it the for you best example is `HTML 5`

Comment: @siva see i updated answer with code for play video in webview also... :)

Comment: @Developer.iOS hey mate now i added code for `webView` also... i used `HTML5` for play the video in iPhone.. but this is simple code for play in `webView`:)

Comment: i dont have any video file it has to load automatically bu using wifi then how can i give path

Comment: @siva see this link for your requirement.. http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Comment: yes it is youtube video only but may change every time,so it is coming from service

Comment: notonly for youtube videos it should also work for other videos

Comment: dont worry use that code it will work. Also i will post my code of HTML5 tommorow... :)

Comment: could u plz give me html 5 coding

Answer (score 0):

just call add your string in this line your are good to go

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your string"]]];
```